# Pass context params with request in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, struts

I have the following URL in my JSP

```jsp
<s:url id="modifyUser" value="%{modifyUserAction}" />
```

and I pass context parameter as follows

```jsp
<s:hidden name="context" value="%{modifyUserContext}"/>
```

But in such way the context will be sent with any URL unless I set not to add params.

How can I pass my context only for specific URL? It must be passed in request, not in URL itself.

Clarification: I want a value from `context` to be passed only with my `modifyUser`, but I *don't* want my URL will look like `someurl?context=someContext`.

Comment: @AleksandrM I want context to be passed in request, not as url parameter.

Comment: Use form-s to post parameters instead get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the context in this way

```jsp
<s:url var="context" value="/" />
```

Now you can use it in the hidden field of the form to make a post request

```jsp
<s:hidden name="context" value="%{#context}"/>
```

Comment: But it will be added to every url. Can I add it only to my modifyUser url?

Comment: No, it won't be added because a POST method is used.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. What i meant, is that this parameter will be passed with every url (suppose i have 3 urls) and I want this to be passed in POST only with 1 url.

Comment: 1) This parameter is not in the URL, parameters are added to the URL if you use GET method. 2)If you want to remove context from the url built with s:url tag then use `includeContext="false"`.